# Facebook's New Page Plugin not working for me?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, plugins

I am trying to use the faceboook's page plugin. 
Following is the link to my page I am trying to use : https://www.facebook.com/iiiftindia

The code goes like this
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/iiiftindia" data- hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true"><div     class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote     cite="https://www.facebook.com/iiiftindia"><a    href="https://www.facebook.com/iiiftindia">IIIFT - Fashion &amp; Interior   Design</a></blockquote></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying without some domain like file://{SOME_HTML} file path. It won't work. For such pugin you need to add the html page in container like apache any php or tomcat then add your content in the html page and hit it in browser it should work.